# Get data from api but got Property 'data' does not exist on type 'object'

Tags: arrays, angular, object, observable, httpclient

I get error: `ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(38,29): error TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Fetch[]'`
[image]

but Fetch has data property
and it's working correctly, so why I got this error?

Comment: Please don't paste code as images, we can't replicate it in that case. Try `.subscribe((res: Fetch) => {...}) `

Comment: @NicholasK now i got this: error TS2345: Argument of type '(res: Fetch) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Fetch[]) => void'.
      Types of parameters 'res' and 'value' are incompatible.
        Type 'Fetch[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Fetch': code, description, data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In statement `this.http.get<Fetch[]>`, the response is expected to be an array of `Fetch`. Please check what is the type of response returned from the API. There are two possibilities.

1. If it an object of type `Fetch`, replace the call with `this.http.get<Fetch>`.
2. If it is an array of object `Fetch`, and if you need to assign an array of the key `data` of the response to `this.response`, then use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
this.response = res.map(r => r.data);
```